# Importing dependency in maven

Tags: java, maven

When importing a maven dependency, a jar, are the files in the `META-INF` are carried over to a hosting project? That is for example, a `persistence.xml` does it get carried over the the host project? Or do I need to re-add it explicitly?

Comment: "are the files in the META-INF are carried over to a hosting project?" are you asking will these files be available in class path? then yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, maven will also move the `META-INF` folder to `target` and thus `persistence.xml` will just be copied to that directory. You won't have to do anything as far as I remember. But you will have to have `META-INF` in your classpath, in your `resources` folder.